# Which one is better to have auto-implemented property with private setter or private field and property just getter?

Tags: c#

My question may be a part of an old topic - "properties vs fields".

I have situation where variable is read-only for outside class but needs to be modified inside a class. I can approach it in 2 ways:

First:

```
private Type m_Field;
public Type MyProperty { get { return m_Field; } }
```

Second:

```
public Type MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

After reading several articles (that mostly covered benefits of using public properties instead of public fields) I did not get idea if the second method has some advantage over the first one but writing less code. I am interested which one will be better practice to use in projects (and why) or it's just a personal choice.

Maybe this question does not belong to SO so I apologize in advance.

Comment: I think you can go ahead with the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version produces less clutter, but is less flexible. I suggest you use the second version until you run into a situation that makes the first version necessary and then refactor - changes will be local to the class anyway, so don't worry too much about that!

Generally, writing less code is a good idea. The less code you write, the less bugs you produce :)

Comment: Example of less flexibility - if you want to give a default initial value to your private field, you'll have to use first only.

Comment: In what way is the second approach less flexible? @Anchit you can set a default value in the constructor just like you would with a private field.

Comment: @James, if you want to do anything with the backing field before setting / getting, then you will need to implement a backing field. But that can easily be done later on and is hardly ever necessary.

Comment: @DarenThomas Yeah I actually meant to delete the first part of my comment. My answer actually demonstrates an example of using it for lazy loading.

Comment: @James What if this field is inside a `static` class?

Comment: @Anchit then you would use a static constructor.

Comment: A correct example of when this is less flexible is if you want to pass it as `ref` or `out` anywhere. That requires a field.

Answer (score 2):

The second one will pretty much compile down to the first one anyway, so IMO always use the second as it's less & neater code.

The only scenarios I tend to use the first approach are when I want to *lazily* load a property e.g.

```
private List<string> _items;
...

public List<string> Items
{
    get
    {
        if (_items == null)
        {
            _items = new List<string>();
            // load items
        }
        return _items;
    }
}
```

Comment: It may seem like a micro-optimization to most folk, however, it plays it's part when you start to write apps for mobile devices where memory resources are limited.

Answer (score 2):

Second version is shorter, so I think it's *usually* better.
The exception is, when the only write access occurs in the constructor. Then I prefer the first version as this allows the field to be marked as `readonly`.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the following question. IT seems like same ,

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72495/net-properties-use-private-set-or-readonly-property

Answer (score 0):

For debugging the second is the best. Otherwise you'll have to put breakpoins at each place where you set the field. With the second you put one breakpoint on the set of the property.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the second version because it is less to write so I can use the time to do more complex coding.... plus in my opinion it promotes lazy development